# Crontab doesn't start my daemon

Tags: debian, cron, daemon

I have a Debian server and I made a daemon and it works fine.

Sometimes this daemon is killed and I made a script to control if daemon is alive or dead. If the script detect that daemon is died then the script will start it.

If I execute my script works fine but if the script is executed by cron then my daemon doesn't start.

**my_script.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash

 if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep my_daemon > /dev/null then
     echo "My Daemon is running " 
 else
     echo "My Daemon is died"
     /etc/init.d/mydaemon start 
 fi
```

**crontab line**

```
## Check my daemon
*/5 * * * *    /etc/script_folder/my_script.sh > /dev/null
```

Could be a permissions problem? Can the cron start daemons?

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info for debugging solutions.

Comment: Crontab is correct, my_script.sh will execute every 5th minute of every hour every day. The problem is the command "/etc/init.d/mydaemon start" when is executed by cron doesn't work.